# DeleteFolder Environ gives an error "Path not found"

Tags: vb.net

here is a portion of the code:

```
oFSO.DeleteFolder Environ("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp") & "\* " & oFSO.GetFile(strZipFile).Name, True
```

when i try to execute it it gives me this error : "Path not found"

Comment: What does the code resolve to? `Environ("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp") & "\* " & oFSO.GetFile(strZipFile).Name` if you output it to the console? What is oFSO? a FileSystemObject? Are you sure this is vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 oFSO.DeleteFolder _ 
      Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp") & _
      ......
```

or use a complicated string concatenation (without the % around the environment variable)

```
 oFSO.DeleteFolder _
 "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\AppData\Local\Temp") & "\* " ....
```

However when dealing with this kind of paths, the best approach is to use Environment class

```
Dim userData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
Dim tempFolder = Path.Combine(userData, "temp")
```

Now the rest of your path seems to be a bit wrong. 
`"* "` (a space after the wild card?) followed by a filename doesn't seems to be correct)